# JSF Converter issue in SelectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, converters

one more time i'm in trouble here. My point is:
In my project i need a converter for (obviously) convert the items from the SelectOneMenu component to a list property in the respective bean. In my jsf page i have:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="ddlPublicType" value="#{publicBean.selectedPublicType}"    effect="fade" converter="#{publicBean.conversor}" > 
    <f:selectItems value="#{publicoBean.lstPublicTypes}" var="pt" itemLabel="#{pt.label}" itemValue="#{pt.value}"></f:selectItems>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

And my bean is:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "publicBean")
@RequestScoped
public class PublicBean {

// Campos
private String name; // Nome do evento
private TdPublicType selectedPublicType = null;
private List<SelectItem> lstPublicTypes = null;
private static PublicTypeDAO publicTypeDao; // DAO 

static {
    publicTypeDao = new PublicTypeDAO();
}
// Construtor

public PublicoBean() {

    lstPublicTypes = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    List<TdPublicType> lst = publicTypeDao.consultarTodos();
    ListIterator<TdPublicType> i = lst.listIterator();
    lst.add(new SelectItem("-1","Select..."));
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        TdPublicType actual = (TdPublicType) i.next();
        lstPublicTypes.add(new SelectItem(actual.getIdPublicType(), actual.getNamePublicType()));
    }

}

// Getters e Setters

...

public Converter getConversor() {
    return new Converter() {
        @Override
        public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
            // This value parameter seems to be the value i had passed into SelectItem constructor
            TdPublicType publicType = null; // Retrieving the PublicType from Database based on ID in value parameter
            try {
                if (value.compareTo("-1") == 0 || value == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                publicType = publicTypeDao.findById(Integer.parseInt(value));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Error in data conversion.");
                msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("info", msg);
            }
            return publicType;
        }

        @Override
        public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
            return value.toString(); // The value parameter is a TdPublicType object ?
        }
    };
}

...
}
```

In the **getAsObject()** method, the value parameter seems to be the value i had passed into SelectItem constructor. But in the **getAsString()** method, the value also seems to be a string representation of an Id. This parameter shouldn't be of type TdPublicType ? There is anything wrong in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `getAsString()` should convert the `Object` (which is in your case of type `TdPublicType`) to a `String` which uniquely identifies the instance, e.g. some ID, so that it can be inlined in HTML code and passed around as HTTP request parameters. The `getAsObject()` should convert exactly that unique `String` representation back to the concrete `Object` instance, so that the submitted HTTP request parameter can be converted back to the original object instance.

Basically (trivial prechecks and exception handling omitted):

```
@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object modelValue) throws ConverterException {
    // Convert Object to unique String representation for display.
    return String.valueOf(((TdPublicType) modelValue).getId());
}

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) throws ConverterException {
    // Convert submitted unique String representation back to Object.
    return tdPublicTypeService.find(Long.valueOf(submittedValue));
}
```

---

**Update**: you've another problem, you're specifying the `value` property of `TdPublicType` class as the item value instead of the `TdPublicType` instance itself. This way the converter will retrieve the `value` property instead of the `TdPublicType` instance in the `getAsString()`. Fix it accordingly:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{publicoBean.lstPublicTypes}" var="pt" 
    itemLabel="#{pt.label}" itemValue="#{pt}"/>
```

Comment: Do i need overload the **toString()** of TdPublicType? Inside the **getAsString()** method is generated an exception saying that was impossible to cast from String to TdPublicType.

Comment: Then the model value is apparently not of type `TdPublicType`. And indeed, you used `itemValue="#{pt.value}"` instead of `itemValue="#{pt}"`. Fix it accordingly.

Comment: He still is returning an Integer as the backing model of the component, but i already has altered the itemValue property to #{pt}.

Comment: I figured out why the value paramater of **getAsString()** is returning an Integer and not a TdPublicType object, i need to have a List<TdPublicType> not List<SelectItem> as the value property of <f:selectItems />.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The `List<SelectItem>` is the old JSF 1.x way. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info

Answer (score 0):

Now the code is working. My error was in the  loading method. I was doing this:

```
// Loading menu
List<TdPublicType> l = daoPublicType.retrieveAll();
Iterator<TdPublicType> i = l.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    TdPublicType actual = (TdPublicType) i.next();
    lstMenuPublicType.add(new SelectItem(actual.getIdtPublicType(), actual.getNamePublicType()));
}
```

But the right way is:

```
// Loading menu
List<TdPublicType> l = daoPublicType.retrieveAll();
Iterator<TdPublicType> i = l.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    TdPublicType actual = (TdPublicType) i.next();
    lstMenuPublicType.add(new SelectItem(actual, actual.getNamePublicType())); // In the first parameter i passed the PublicType object itself not his id.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use can use generic converter which will convert the value in the backing bean.
You do not need any casting also.

```
@FacesConverter(value = "GConverter")
public class GConverter implements Converter{

    private static Map<Object, String> entities = new WeakHashMap<Object, String>();

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object entity) {
        synchronized (entities) {
            if (!entities.containsKey(entity)) {
                String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                entities.put(entity, uuid);
                return uuid;
            } else {
                return entities.get(entity);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String uuid) {
        for (Entry<Object, String> entry : entities.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue().equals(uuid)) {
                return entry.getKey();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Example usage would be

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="ddlPublicType" value="#{publicBean.selectedPublicType}"    effect="fade" converter="GConverter" > 
    <f:selectItems value="#{publicoBean.lstPublicTypes}" var="pt" itemLabel="#{pt.label}" itemValue="#{pt}"></f:selectItems>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Warning: this converter is memory inefficient and may cause memory leaks when 2nd level database cache is used. It's NOT recommended for production environments. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/30186849

Comment: no glitches till now , we have been using this converter for quite a long time. however, thanks for the information . we will certainly look for some other options as well