# Arguments against a generic JSF object converter with a static WeakHashMap

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, converters

I want to avoid boiler plate code for creating a list of SelectItems to map my entities/dtos between view and model, so I used this [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21837334/pautocomplete-for-a-global-entity-converter/21837399#21837399) of a generic object converter:

```
@FacesConverter(value = "objectConverter")
public class ObjectConverter implements Converter {

private static Map<Object, String> entities = new WeakHashMap<Object, String>();

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object entity) {
    synchronized (entities) {
        if (!entities.containsKey(entity)) {
            String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            entities.put(entity, uuid);
            return uuid;
        } else {
            return entities.get(entity);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String uuid) {
    for (Entry<Object, String> entry : entities.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().equals(uuid)) {
            return entry.getKey();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

There are already many [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6173392/3698894) to similliar questions, but I want a vanilla solution (without *faces). The following points still leave me uncertain about the quality of my snippet:

1. If it was that easy, why isn't there a generic object converter build into [JSF](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaqd.html#bnaqi)?
2. Why are so many people still using [SelectItems](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsConverter)? Isn't there more flexibility by using the generic approach? E.g. #{dto.label} can be quickly changed into #{dto.otherLabel}.
3. Given the scope is just to map between view and model, is there any major downside of the generic approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This approach is hacky and memory inefficient.

It's "okay" in a small application, but definitely not in a large application with tens or hundreds of thousands of potential entities around which could be referenced in a `f:selectItems`. Moreover, such a large application has generally a second level entity cache. The `WeakHashMap` becomes then useless and is only effective when an entity is physically removed from the underlying datastore (and thus also from second level entity cache).

It has certainly a "fun" factor, but I'd really not recommend using it in "heavy production".

If you don't want to use an existing solution from an utility library like [OmniFaces `SelectItemsConverter`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsConverter) as you already found, which is basically completely stateless and doesn't use any DAO/Service call, then your best bet is to abstract all your entities with a common base interface/class and hook the converter on that instead. This only still requires a DAO/Service call. This has been fleshed out in detail in this Q&A: [Implement converters for entities with Java Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343032/implement-converters-for-entities-with-java-generics).