# How to use SelectManyCheckbox with ArrayList as HashMap value

Tags: jsf, primefaces, mojarra

Im trying to bind selected values of SelectManyCheckbox to ArrayList, which is the value of my HashMap.

If my options are inside an ArrayList and selected options are aswell. i have no issue.

BUT when i want to set these selected options as a value of a map. it will populate an array of Object[] no matter what i try.

im using Mojarra 4.0.5.

## MyBean

```
@Component
@ViewScoped
@Getter
@Setter
public class TestView {
    Map<String, ArrayList<Dto>> map;
    ArrayList<String> strings;
    ArrayList<Dto> options;
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Dto dto1 = new Dto();
        Dto dto2 = new Dto();
        dto1.setAge(1);
        dto1.setName("OPTION1");
        dto2.setAge(2);
        dto2.setName("OPTION2");
        options = new ArrayList<Dto>();
        options.add(dto1);
        options.add(dto2);
        map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Dto>>();
        strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        strings.add(new String("TEST1"));
        strings.add(new String("TEST2"));
        
        strings.forEach(s -> map.put(s, new ArrayList<Dto>()));
    }
    public void debug() {
        System.out.println("debug");
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Dto>> testarr = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Dto>>();
        map.forEach((k,v)->testarr.add(v));
    }
    
}
```

## Dto

```
public class Dto {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

## Converter

```
@FacesConverter(value="myConverter")
public class MyConverter implements Converter<Dto> {

    private Map<Dto, String> entities = new HashMap<Dto, String>();

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Dto value) {
        synchronized (entities) {
            if (!entities.containsKey(value)) {
                String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                entities.put(value, uuid);
                return uuid;
            } else {
                return entities.get(value);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dto getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        for (Map.Entry<Dto, String> entry : entities.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue().equals(value)) {
                return entry.getKey();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

## Xhtml

```
<ui:repeat var="str" value="#{testView.strings}" varStatus="strStatus">
    <ui:param name="indexStr" value="#{strStatus.index}" />
    <p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{testView.map[str]}"
        converter="myConverter" layout="responsive" columns="6">
        <p:ajax process="@this" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{testView.options}" var="item"
            itemLabel="#{item.name}" itemValue="#{item}" />
    </p:selectManyCheckbox>
</ui:repeat>
<p:commandButton value="debug" icon="pi pi-check" process="@this"
    action="#{testView.debug()}" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're victim of type erasure in generics.

Basically, in raw Java source code you have `Map<String, ArrayList<Dto>> map`.

But in the compiled output of that code it has become `Map map` and information about `String` and `ArrayList<Dto>` is lost.

This is the same problem the EL expressions `#{...}` are facing. When it tries to inspect the type of `value="#{testView.map[str]}"` via [`ValueExpression#getType()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/expression-language/4.0/apidocs/jakarta/el/valueexpression#getType-jakarta.el.ELContext-) it retrieves `java.lang.Object` not `java.lang.ArrayList`.

Technically speaking, setting `collectionType` attribute as follows must work

```xml
<p:selectManyCheckbox ... collectionType="java.util.ArrayList">
```

But to my surprise it indeed doesn't have any effect. It would only work if the `java.lang.Object` was actually an instance of `java.util.Collection`. I consider this a bug in Mojarra. I've fixed this via [issue 5427](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/5427).

By the way, your converter is not thread safe and it's not entirely memory efficient: [Arguments against a generic JSF object converter with a static WeakHashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30186849/arguments-against-a-generic-jsf-object-converter-with-a-static-weakhashmap). Take a look at [OmniFaces `SelectItemsConverter`](https://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsConverter).

Comment: thank you for addressing this issue. it was driving me crazy and i did not like the idea of converting my array of Object[] to arrayList of desired time.
I will give a look to omnifaces converter, thank you.